# How to recover mail server from POP3 mails?

Tags: email, imap, thunderbird, email-server, pop3

Unfortunately I've used POP3 to synchronize my mails from www.gmx.ch with Thunderbird Mozilla Firefox (incoming mails: pop.gmx.net port 995) and (outgoing mails: mail.gmx.net port 465). The box delete mails from Server after 14 days has been checked. Now almost all mails from the server has been deleted. Is it somehow possible to transfer the mails backwards to the GMX-Mail-Server?

Comment: Yes, there *should* be a way to upload your emails back to the mail server. Do you by chance have an imap port you can use?

Comment: Hi Tom. I don't know. How can I find out if it works what you are thinking about?

Comment: If you are not asking us for an app, just how to use Thunderbird, you should probably ask at https://superuser.com/  I know that TB can export, so the only question is whether GMX can import. I am unsure what would happen if you reconfigured TB to use GMX's IMAP settings, but that might work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if there could be any solution to this. IMAP account takes a copy of emails to the locations configured. However, POP accounts simply moves them permanently. Deletion is therefore permanent.

We are offered a limited space in our office. Exceeding that space leads us to a fine. We have therefore configured our accounts through POP. The mails download to our local servers. To avoid deletion and hardware crashes, we have backed them up to DropBox through Mail Backup X. That helps us in many ways.

*References:*

Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/

Mail Backup X: http://www.mailbackupx.com/download.html

Comment: If mails can be moved in one direction, then why not in the other?

Comment: That needs special access. For example, there is GSuite/GApps. You seek special permissions to load your emails back to the server. Enlighten me, if I am wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you know more than I do :-) I just guessed that if I "made an email appear" on one IMAP device, by importing it, then it would "magically" appear on other linked devices. Live & learn ;-)

Comment: If you can configure IMAP access, do so, and then drag the mail from your local folder(s) back to your server's inbox on the imap side, and then delete the POP3 settings/connection

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do [this](https://superuser.com/questions/517751/is-it-possible-to-upload-that-email-back-to-the-server):

1. Backup your e-mails in case you break something. Backup them outside Thunderbird.
2. Add a new account to Thunderbird connected to your [www.gmx.ch](http://www.gmx.ch) inbox with IMAP. This way you should now have 2 accounts in Thunderbird connected to your [www.gmx.ch](http://www.gmx.ch) inbox: one with IMAP and one with POP3.
3. Now change the password to the [www.gmx.ch](http://www.gmx.ch) inbox POP3 account and put a **wrong password**. This way we will be safe and we will be assured that no e-mails will be downloaded again with POP3
4. Now in Thunderbird drag & drop the e-mails from the POP3 inbox to the IMAP inbox and repeat the same action for each folder (spam, junk, deleted, sent, draft, etc...). You can also select all the e-mail, right click and move to the folder you want.